# Return Custom 404 Error when resource not found in Django Rest Framework

Tags: python, django, rest, django-rest-framework

I am learning [Django Rest Framework](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/), and also new to django. I want to return a custom `404` error in json when a client will access a resource which was not found.

My `urls.py` looks liks this:

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^mailer/$', views.Mailer.as_view(), name='send-email-to-admin')
]
```

In which i have only one resource, which can be accessed through URI, **http://localhost:8000/mailer/**

Now, when a client access any other URI like **http://localhost:8000/**, API should return a `404-Not Found` error like this:

```
{
    "status_code" : 404
    "error" : "The resource was not found"
}
```

Please suggest some answer with proper code snippets, if suitable.

Comment: i am using `custom_exception_handler` method  described in [Django REST framework exceptions](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/exceptions/) , to catch exceptions which will raise in function_view or class_views .

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You are looking for [`handler404`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/urls/#handler404).

Here is my suggestion:

1. Create a view that should be called if none of the URL patterns match.
2. Add `handler404 = path.to.your.view` to your root URLconf.

Here is how it's done:

1. `project.views`

   ```
   from django.http import JsonResponse


   def custom404(request, exception=None):
       return JsonResponse({
           'status_code': 404,
           'error': 'The resource was not found'
       })
   ```
2. `project.urls`

   ```
   from project.views import custom404


   handler404 = custom404
   ```

Read [error handling](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/http/urls/#error-handling) for more details.

[Django REST framework exceptions](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/exceptions/) may be useful as well.

Comment: this solution doesn't work, i did as you described.I also set `DEBUG=False`.But, it return html page, **Not Found

The requested URL / was not found on this server.**

Comment: @AkshayPratapSingh Seems like I misunderstood you. Edited my answer and it should work now.

Comment: i am using this method to catch rest_framwork view's errors, but it does not catch url route non-matched error, which return 404 error.

Comment: You should also include status code 404: `JsonResponse({'detail': "The resource was not found",
                         'status_code': 404}, status=404)`

Answer (score 6):

according to django documentation :
 Django runs through each URL pattern, in order, and stops at the first one that matches the requested URL. ref: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/http/urls/

so you can just add another url in urlpatterns after the one you created and it should match all url patterns and send them to a view that return the 404 code.

i.e :

```
urlpatterns = [
url(r'^mailer/$', views.Mailer.as_view(), name='send-email-to-admin'),
url(r'^.*/$',views.Error404.as_view(),name='error404')]
```

Comment: what should i do to make Error404 class view, such that it return  my customized `JsonResponse` in call of each HTTP methods.

Comment: Is there any way to write one single method in Class View, which handle all HTTP methods, rather write for separate method for each HTTP method.

Comment: your solution also works but i used function `@api_view` not class based view , so that api return same `JsonResponse` on calling each HTTP method.

Answer (score 0):

@Ernest Ten's answer is correct. However, I would like to add some input if you're using an application that handles both browser page loading and API as call.

I customized the `custom404` function to this

```
def custom404(request, exception=None):
    requested_html = re.search(r'^text/html', request.META.get('HTTP_ACCEPT')) # this means requesting from browser to load html
    api = re.search(r'^/api', request.get_full_path()) # usually, API URLs tend to start with `/api`. Thus this extra check. You can remove this if you want.

    if requested_html and not api:
        return handler404(request, exception) # this will handle error in the default manner

    return JsonResponse({
        'detail': _('Requested API URL not found')
    }, status=404, safe=False)
```

Answer (score 0):

update of [Ernest Ten answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31381075/2351696):

You should also include
in **urls.py**

```
from django.http import JsonResponse
...other urls...
handler404 = lambda request, exception=None: JsonResponse({'error': '404: The resource was not found'}, status=404)
```